# Look who's talking

Tags: metaphors

English isn’t my main language, so maybe this isn’t a tough one.

Is there a metaphor to say “he’s talking about this deed as a wrong one but he certainly does it too’?

In Spanish, you could say something like “about ears is the donkey talking”. Is there a similar phrase, in English?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A corresponding English expression is:

> The pot calling the kettle black

Wikipedia has [a page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pot_calling_the_kettle_black) with equivalents in many languages.

Comment: Excelent Wiki link.

Answer (score 4):

I think the phrase you're looking for is:

> It's the pot calling the kettle black.

or

> People in glass houses should not throw stones.

Edit to add: some people are of the mistaken impression that the former expression has a racist history. This is not true, but enough people seem to think this (although still a small number) that the latter expression might be favored.

Comment: "People in glass houses shouldn't throw stones" is more an adage warning people in precarious moral positions not to point out the moral faults of others. It's closer to the Biblical "let he who has not sinned cast the first stone", while "look who's talking" is more "why do you notice the splinter in your friend's eye, but do not notice the log in your own?"

Comment: @KeithS: it is different from the former expression, but I think it also reflects this part from the question: "He's talking about this deed as a wrong one but he certainly does it too."

Answer (score 2):

"Look who's talking" is a present-day analog of the old Latin "Tu quoque" (You too), which has other modern evolutions in present-day Romance languages ("Y tu", "et vous") which figuratively mean the same thing. It is an inductive reasoning element used to cast doubt on one's opponent in an argument or debate; The context is that the opponent is advocating that either the speaker or a third person should exude some moral quality which they do not themselves possess. The term thus implies that the other person doesn't do what they are advocating, so why should anyone else?

For example:

Dad - "Son, I'm sick and tired of you coming home at midnight smelling of booze. You should drink less and come home earlier."
Mom (to Dad) - "Look who's talking! You only got here thirty minutes before him, and I smelled whisky on your breath!"

Popular synonymous adages include:

- Listen to the pot calling the kettle black
- Take a page from your own book
- Practice what you preach
- Holy Bible, Matthew 7 (NIV): "Why do you look at the speck of sawdust in your brother’s eye and pay no attention to the plank in your own eye?"

Comment: The Dad needs to get divorced and the Son needs to get the heck out of the house and get a job if he's old enough to be drinking like that.